# How do I disable the "Save to network" option on OpenTTD for Android?

Tags: android, openttd

I use OpenTTD on an Android device that does not have an Internet connection or Google account associated with it. By default, "Save to network" is enabled in the Save game menu.

The problem is that my Android device will show a spinner about trying to access the network, followed by the app crashing. Fortunately, it appears that the game is saved to internal storage before the attempted network access, so the game is not lost. However, it's extremely annoying to have to reopen OpenTTD every time you save the game (and I save frequently, just in case something happens).

I have researched this online, but all the information I can find tells you to click the depressed "Save to network" button to disable the feature. This makes sense. Unfortunately, it appears that disabling this feature also requires network access, so the app crashes, and the feature is not disabled.

How do I disable this feature in OpenTTD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some trial and error to figure out the solution, but it turns out that it was quite simple.

In your `openttd.cfg` file, there should be a line that looks somewhat like the following:

`save_to_network = ask`

Although this would seem to imply that I am normally offered the chance to turn this off, OpenTTD never asked me whether I wanted to use it. If you change `ask` to `0`, the problem will be resolved. Fire up OpenTTD again, and you will now see that the `Save to network` button is no longer depressed!

**How I figured this out**

By reading the OpenTTD for Android source code, I found that the `save_to_network` value is treated as a boolean (true/false), except that it is an integer. In this case, the numbers `0` and `1` are used to represent `false` and `true`, respectively. If `save_to_network` is `1`, the button will be depressed, and OpenTTD will try to save to the network. Otherwise, it will ignore that feature, which is what I wanted.